# How to download DB file using phonegap?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, file-transfer

I have an offline application which once in a while needs to download the updated DB from external server. I tried it according to the link [Sample code to download file from internet](https://gist.github.com/nathanpc/2464060)

The application now downloads the file properly but somehow the file is changed. DB file after downloading doesn't, it asks for password which not being set. Please let me know if thers any other way to do the same thing..